# React native IOS app crashing on Xcode 13.2.1 real device only

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, crash, native

This crash has been only on real device. It works fine on the simulator without error.

this is my log when running the app on Xcode 13.2.1 :

```
2022-04-15 07:09:38.578817+0200 MYAPP[1352:356163] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate>  application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2022-04-15 07:09:38.581802+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: 
2022-04-15 07:09:38.627502+0200 MYAPP[1352:356368] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60900000 started
2022-04-15 07:09:38.628907+0200 MYAPP[1352:356368] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2022-04-15 07:09:38.637544+0200 MYAPP[1352:356340] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
/firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2022-04-15 07:09:38.639510+0200 MYAPP[1352:356163] 
[CodePush] Loading JS bundle from file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3BDE599F-E11E-4070-A460-4882CEAE4C63/MYAPP.app/main.jsbundle
2022-04-15 07:09:38.699 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:294] Running application MYAPP ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2022-04-15 07:09:38.881871+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-04-15 07:09:38.882411+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-04-15 07:09:38.887530+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-04-15 07:09:38.887647+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-04-15 07:09:38.888159+0200 MYAPP[1352:356364] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C3] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-04-15 07:09:38.888377+0200 MYAPP[1352:356364] TCP Conn 0x282b18d10 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2022-04-15 07:09:38.888774+0200 MYAPP[1352:356368] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C2] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2022-04-15 07:09:38.888945+0200 MYAPP[1352:356368] TCP Conn 0x282b18c60 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2022-04-15 07:09:39.002512+0200 MYAPP[1352:356367] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2022-04-15 07:09:39.077983+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2022-04-15 07:09:39.078086+0200 MYAPP[1352:356365] 6.34.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2022-04-15 07:09:39.328 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Error: Cannot use t "__Schema" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
2022-04-15 07:09:39.339 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2022-04-15 07:09:39.341 [info][tid:main][RCTSurface.mm:306] Running surface LogBox ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 11;
})
2022-04-15 07:09:39.342 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2022-04-15 07:09:40.342 [info][tid:main][RCTLogBox.mm:52] Failed to mount LogBox within 1s
```

**Details**

```
Could not launch “MYAPP”

Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain

Code: 3

Failure Reason: invalid file descriptor: "fd://4294967295"
```

```
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "invalid file descriptor: \"fd://4294967295\"";
}
--
```

```
Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "14.4 (18D52)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 26428;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--
```

**System Information**

- macOS Version 11.4 (Build 20F71)
- Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)

Answer (score 0):

**I think the problem may be this error in your log output.**

```
Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.

    2022-04-15 07:09:39.339 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    2022-04-15 07:09:39.341 [info][tid:main][RCTSurface.mm:306] Running surface 

    LogBox ({
        initialProps =     {
        };
        rootTag = 11;
    })

    2022-04-15 07:09:39.342 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    2022-04-15 07:09:40.342 [info][tid:main][RCTLogBox.mm:52] Failed to mount LogBox within 1s
```